# Selenium on Colab: Wrong results from text extraction in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

When I am using Chromedriver in Python to scrape a certain website I only get wrong results if I am running the script via Colab. If I am using Spyder for example everything seems to work fine.

It seems to me, that Selenium is still finding the right elements, but it extracts weird numbers, which I can find nowhere on the website.

Website with results:
Website with desired numbers (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEKbh.png)

What Colab returns:
Results from Colab(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EbOM.png)

Website: "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/croatia/hnl/hnk-gorica-varazdin-Kr4sLgwt/#1X2;2"

I am using this function to test:

```
def fi(a):
try:
    driver.find_element("xpath", a).text
except:
    return False
```

And this one to get the text:

```
def ffi(a):
if fi(a) != False :
    return driver.find_element("xpath", a).text
```

And this is the full code

```
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/croatia/hnl/hnk-gorica-varazdin-Kr4sLgwt/#1X2;2")

for j in range(1,15):
print(j)
book= ffi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[1]'.format(j))

if fi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[2]//preceding-sibling::a'.format(j))==False:
    Odd_1=ffi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[2]'.format(j))
else:
    Odd_1=fi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//a)[5]'.format(j))
    
if fi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[3]//preceding-sibling::a'.format(j))==False:
    Odd_X=ffi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[3]'.format(j))
else:
    Odd_X=ffi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//a)[6]'.format(j))       

if fi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[4]//preceding-sibling::a'.format(j))==False:
    Odd_2=ffi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//p)[4]'.format(j))
else:
    Odd_2=ffi('((//*[starts-with(@class,"flex text-xs max")])[{}]//a)[7]'.format(j))

ab= (ffi('//div[contains(@class,"flex items-center w-full h-auto")]//p'))
bc=(ffi('(//div[contains(@class,"flex px")]//child::div)[3]'))       
print(book, Odd_1, Odd_X, Odd_2,ab ,bc)
```

Once again it is working fine on spyder

EDIT: I have run this code via Replit, so I can see the Webpage. It turns out, that for some reason THE WHOLE SITE is being loaded with wrong values. So basiccaly the code is fine, but the website is wrong. I am more confused than ever.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUwir.png)

Comment: can you share the colab notebook link? or simply the code

Comment: Seems your locators are off. Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: I've tested the locators multiple times with my browser and they work fine on my local setup

Answer (score 0):

Your IP and language identifictors might change when using Google Colab. This might cause inconsistency or different page layouts.

Try screenshotting and getting the page-source and compare to your local tests.
Also ckeck, if you locator still matches up with the page-sourcode in colab

Also make shure, that you're using the same browser.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I see the page-source from colab, if it is running on headless mode? With browser you mean both on Chrome for example, right?

Comment: For viewing the page-source you can execute `print(driver.page_source)`
Yes, exactly.

Comment: I just noticed that the numbers are nearly always off by a certain pattern: 2,25 --> 125 & 3,45 -->245

Comment: Well maybe that's the solution:)

Comment: There is a pattern, but it seems to fluctuate --> *100 +100 another time *100 + 600. Honestly I am a little lost. Although it shows me, that I am pulling the correct Identifcators, I don't see the reason for these wrong numbers.

Comment: Well that's weird. I'll might have a look in some time:)

Comment: That would be so nice, but maybe do you know another Tool where I can run a python script on a server, where I can also use selenium. Nevertheless thank you very much!

Comment: Well me personally, I'm using [Selenium-profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles),  and also with Google-Colab.
There's a example script for colab: https://colab.research.google.com/github/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/blob/master/google-colab/selenium_profiles.ipynb

Comment: Okay, sounds interesting. Are the methods similar to the "normal" Selenium?

Comment: Well yeah. There are some additions tho: Undetectability (for example by cloudfare, google) and Device emulation (which makes tests more consistent on different platforms)

Comment: Sadly the same error occured with selenium-profiles :(

Comment: Oh well:/ Did you try getting `all_values = driver.get_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div")`
And then parsing those values without Selenium?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean, tbh. I have tried the wuery again with replit and got the same error. I think some of the chrome options I use could be the problem, because the are exactly the same like in colab:---------------------                                       
 chrome_options = Options()----------------------------------
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')---------------------
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

Comment: I edited my question. Via Replit i´ve noticed that the whole site is being loaded wrong. I am pulling the correct data, but the data is just simply wrong. Do you know a reason why thos could be the case?

Comment: Well no Idea tbh

Comment: Yeah me too. But still thank you very much!